# How to create emberjs services similar to angular?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I switched from angular to ember and I miss the ability to create a service that I can share across different components.  Say I have a validation service or rest service or even a logging service.

What is the best way to create such a cross-cutting service in ember that I can use from different routes, controllers, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something what we call a `Mixin` in Ember. [Mixins documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html).

Example:

```
App.SortableMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({

    sort: function () {
        // do some facy sorting here (pro-tip: there actually is a mixin that does sorting!)
    }
});

App.MyController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(App.SortableMixin, {

    initialize: function(){
        this.sort(); // calls the App.SortableMixin sort function
    }.on('init');
});
```

You could use this `Mixin` on controllers, models or routes.

Comment: interesting!!!  I actually wrote a pagination mixin but didn't to think of using a mixin as a service - i guess that should work.